# CodeIgniter on localhost : Too many redirects

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

For testing purpose, I copied all the code and DB records from our live server to a local server.

I edited the following files :

**/application/config/config.php (I also edited the DB record)**

```
//$config['base_url']   = 'https://www.OurWebsite.eu/';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';
```

**index.php**

```
//define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

**/application/config/database.php**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'test_localhost';
$db['default']['password'] = '**************';
```

But when I open a web browser I have to following error :

Firefox : `The page is not well redirected`

Chrome : `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

I already tried to change this in **/application/config/config.php**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

With all others values but none of them worked.

I also tried to delete my **.htaccess** without success.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond $1 !^(themes)

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|static|img|css|js|map|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|png)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/ico text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/rss+xml application/atom_xml text/javascript
```

The live server is running without errors with the exactly same code.
I do not really know how to proceed...
I never used CodeIgniter before, I may need a particular PHP extension enabled ?

Comment: This code looks like fine. May be you were making any logical mistake in controllers while redirecting, and may be it creates a loop. 
Once I faced the same issue, In my case I was redirecting to login page when a user try to access dashboard without login and a user logged In I was trying to redirect to dashboard even he/she tried to access login page.

Comment: @AniketSingh Is there anyway to know which controller is used first in codeIgniter ?

Comment: open file `application/config/routes.php` and search for line `$route['default_controller'] = 'login';` in my case default controller is `Login`.
Whenever you hit your base url ('http://localhost/test/'); It will execute code of constructor of default controller then of index function of the same controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I had to write this in my .htacces

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

in the **/application/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.my-site.local/'; //Don't forget the final '/'
```

And in the database : `http://www.my-site.local` (without the trailing `/`)

Answer (score 1):

if you have used redirect in constructor than remove it i have the same problem but at last concluded that i have used redirect in constructor for login session

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I check project session array variables which variable use for check valid user that variable does not exist in this session array that's why it cause that's the problem (too-many-redirects). Check it's your session array or other variables.
**Maybe it's helpful for you.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a space in one of the folder names in the url: http://localhost/some%20folder/admin/

Renaming the folder to remove the space fixed the issue.